# When I try to install wine-stable-amd64 or wine-stable-i386, It has problems with libc6 - SOLVED

Tags: package-management, 20.04, wine, amd-ryzen

[image: held broken packages]

[image: recommends]

I have also tried to downgrade libc6 to 2.31-0ubuntu9, but it's the same result.

Also I am on a AMD Ryzen 3 3200g.

Edit: Cerberos, I followed the instructions, aaaand, it worked flawlessly. Thank you kind sir. Sorry for taking a bit to respond, been busy. ALSO, reseting repositories also played a part, thank to you also n0bert.

Comment: The issue of your problem probably consists in broken packages. I had a similar problem and this article helped me to fix the issue. Should also work on 20.04 https://omgfoss.com/how-to-fix-broken-packages-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/ Tell me, when it doesn't help.

Comment: Try just installing wine instead of wine-stable.  My wine install does not have the wine-stable packages.